# Python Not Finding Key Value

Tags: python, dictionary, key

Below is an excerpt from my code that I am having troubles with. The problem is simply that the code isn't finding the the key in the dictionary, as stated by the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "G:\Game.py", line 386, in <module>
battle()
File "G:\Game.py", line 197, in battle
if int(playerStats["playerExperience"]) > int(levels['{0}'.format("{0}".format(playerStats['level']))]):
KeyError: 'level'
```

These are the two parts of the code that apply:

```
global playerStats
      if int(playerStats["playerExperience"]) > int(levels['{0}'.format("{0}".format(playerStats['level']))]):
```

and

```
global playerStats
playerStats={
 "playerMaxHp":"0",
 "playerCurrentHp":"0",
 "playerAtk":"0",
 "playerDef":"0",
 "playerDefending":"0",
 "playerRunAblility":"0",
 "playerExperience":"0",
 "level":"1"
 }
```

EDIT: And 'levels' refers to this here:

```
levels={ #"Level"="Experience"
 "2":"5",
 "3":"12",
 "4":"20",
 }
```

EDIT2: Added another value to levels:

```
levels={ #"Level"="Experience"
 "1":"0",
 "2":"5",
 "3":"12",
 "4":"20",
 }
```

SOLVED:
The problem was that in an earlier line of code, I was replacing the dictionary, and not adding to it. Once I fixed that, the code worked fine.

Comment: You should try to print `playerStats['level']` above your if condition and see what it prints or returns which exception.

Comment: seems you `playerStats['level']` is assigned at the below. it's weird. but you can use `get` method to have a default value if key is not exist.

Comment: Sorry, but you haven't given enough information.  There is more going on here than what you show above, either post more code or create a bare minimum working example of this problem.

Comment: I do not want to have a default key, because the value of level should change often, and a default would eliminate the usefulness of what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, what is this doubling:

```
'{0}'.format("{0}".format(playerStats['level']))
```

One format is enough, I think. (Actually, since the value of `playerStats['level']` is already a string, you can leave the format out completely.) Secondly, what is `levels`? Is it a list? A dictionary? If you pass the `playerStats` dictionary into that, you will evaluate to this:

```
if int('0') > int(levels['1']):
```

So if `levels['1']` is a valid item, it should work. But if `levels` is a list or tuple, or a dictionary without a `'1'` key, it won't.

Comment: I've had some problems when trying to enter things similar to this without the .format(). Maybe I am being a little over the top, I've tried many things. Some with the .format's, some without. This was it in its current state. None of the things I've tried (including the lack of duplication) make any difference.
'levels' is:
levels={ #"Level"="Experience"
     "2":"5",
     "3":"12",
     "4":"20",
     }
I have this to determine the points at which the playerStats['level'] should increase.

Comment: It looks as if your `levels` dict does not have a key `'1'`, only a `'2'` through `'4'`. But that still doesn't explain the `'level'` key error. I would recommend Tanveer Alam's idea of printing `playerStats` in its entirety before this line so that you can find out why it doesn't have a `'level'` key.

Comment: That was true. I didn't. I added it, and it didn't fix the problem. It is still having the KeyError: 'level'.

Comment: Can you do me a favour and add `print(playerStats)` just before the if statement and tell us the output of that print statement?

Comment: This is what is printed right before the error. """You gained 1 experience!
{'playerExperience': '1'}""" (minus the triple quotes, of course.)

Comment: That explains it: The dictionary is not complete. It only has a single key/value pair: `'playerExperience': '1'`, no `'level'`

Answer (score 0):

Well, your code run well to me.

Instead of using strings, why don't you use integers. Something like this

```
global playerStats
playerStats={
 "playerMaxHp": 0,
 "playerCurrentHp": 0,
 "playerAtk": 0,
 "playerDef": 0,
 "playerDefending": 0,
 "playerRunAblility": 0,
 "playerExperience": 0,
 "level": 1
 }

levels={ #"Level"="Experience"
 1: 0,
 2: 5,
 3: 12,
 4: 20
 }

if playerStats["playerExperience"] > levels[playerStats['level']]:
    pass
    # do something
else:
    pass
    # do something
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with ' instead of " :

```
playerStats={
'playerMaxHp': 0,
'playerCurrentHp': 0,
'playerAtk': 0,
'playerDef': 0,
'playerDefending': 0,
'playerRunAblility': 0,
'playerExperience': 0,
'level': 1
}
```

And the same for the accesors: if playerStats['playerExperience'] > ....

Comment: No, that does not make a difference in Python.

Comment: I'd rather keep the values as strings. I've had problems when they were values. Plus, the problem isn't from the values. The problem lies in the fact that, for some reason, it can't find the key 'level'.